# "Install" button disabled for Haskell GHC installer on my Mac. Please help, nothing works

Tags: xcode, macos, haskell, installation

I was hoping Haskell would be the first programming language I would learn, but I can't even get to square 1: when I run the GHC..pkg, the "install button" is greyed out.  I tried asking at the Haskell irc, but I'm always asked whether I have Xcode installed.  I have Xcode 3.2.4 installed on my computer, so there should be no problem, as it's up to date with the latest GHC package.

I'm completely stuck, any help is appreciated.

Comment: fakaff, I don't know how to test this, but I remember just this problem with the first version of the Haskell Platform; I had installed the 'Developer Tools' on one of my machines, but foolishly was confident it was the one in question.  I think in the end it was the lack of the 'Developer Tools' version of the gcc that was the trouble. My only wisdom will echo what you've heard, that you might be missing some crucial chunk from the Developer Tools stuff.

Comment: hm. I can't say I remember. I'm downloading Xcode again.  The download looks like it'll take a while but I'll see what happens when I re-install it and make sure not to uncheck anything like that.

Comment: Take a look at the page linking an OS X binary and packaged source for the version of the GHC that will be used in the next version of the Platform http://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_7_0_1 . It and the similar pages for past versions mention that "The package requires Xcode 3.1 (in particular, the "Unix Development Support") to be already installed."  Is it possible that you failed to make sure the UNIX Dev Support box was ticked on the Installation Type panel in the XCode installer?

Comment: OK.  I've re-installed Xcode with the UNIX Dev box checked and it works. <p> Thanks! this should be more prominent in the documentation for us newbs.

Comment: fakaff, AWESOME! I agree it is a completely baffling error, it occurs to me now that it might show up in Console.app.  The remarks on  haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_7_0_1 should in any case be added to the Platform OS X page, together with the point that ~/.cabal/bin is the default home of cabal-installed executables and thus needs to be added to the $PATH variable.

Answer (score 1):

Is this on the step where you choose the install location? I think you need to click on the drive (even if there's only one) before you can press the install button.

Comment: No, the trouble precedes that;  if you don't have XCode installed, or have the wrong bit of it, then the GHC installer will keep the very first button you might click grey and inactive.  The simple solution would probably be to include the reminder text  "The package requires Xcode 3.1 (in particular, the "Unix Development Support") to be already installed." on the initial panel.

Answer (score 0):

I know you already solved your problem, but maybe this is useful for someone else.

If you already have Xcode you could install Homebrew, a package manager for OSX:

https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew

Once you have that, Haskell is just a

```
brew install haskell-platform
```

away.

Comment: Bavarious, these are all very different ways of installing the GHC and the Platform libraries. The Homebrew method is quite different from Fink and MacPorts, since it uses the standard Platform installer, which hooks the ghc up with native OS X libraries, as homebrew generally attempts to do.  Some of the ins and outs as they stood a few months ago are spread around in this discussion: http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/d9wm2/is_it_time_for_a_strike_team_to_form_dedicated_to/ Perhaps there is somewhere a more up to date and focussed overview of the options at the moment.